# Setting Firestore Emulator with Flutter test hangs

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli, flutter-test

I'm trying to write Unit Tests using Firestore Emulator.

I've started the emulator with the following command :

```
firebase emulators:start --only firestore
```

The test is as follow :

```
  testWidgets('should retrieve correct item', (tester) async {
    await Firestore.instance.settings(
      host: "127.0.0.1:8080",
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false,
    );

    var ref = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('books')
      .add({ 'title': 'title'});

    // Fetch item by id
    var resp = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('books')
      .document(ref.documentID)
      .get();

    expect(resp, isNotNull);

  });
```

The problem is that the code hangs on the `.settings()` method and never proceed to the next steps.

Fun fact is when I stop the emulator, the tests acts the same and hangs on the `.add()` method, making me wonder if the way I'm doing it is the right way.

Comment: Actually widget tests would mock and prevent any network calls be it localhost or to a server. Try mocking the class if you had to test a widget based on Firestore results. Else, just try to use. `test` method from `package:test` for unit tests.

Comment: Well thank you for this information. I wasn't aware that widget tests prevented any network access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), that's not the right way to test stuff. Probably the test hangs as it can't communicate with Firebase at that address.

Every time you have a piece of code that's hard to test, either because it's slow or needs network access (APIs, Databases etc.) you should [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) it.

I recommend you take a look at the [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) packages.

Use Provider to inject dependencies (`Firebase.instance` on this case) into your actual code and when testing you can inject a mock of Firebase that actually does nothing instead using Mockito and still validate all calls to Firebase were correct.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of dependency injection and am planning to use [Cloud Firestore Mocks](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_mocks). This piece of code is just the most simple code to reproduce the problem, getting rid of anything irrelevant to the question and trying to explore the usage of Firestore emulator. Anyway, I wasn't aware that widget tests prevented any network usage and will stick to mocking

Comment: That's Ok, but you shouldn't edit people's answers adding information, it sounds as if they said it, it should be a comment instead. It looks like I am suggesting this package, but I never used it myself so I can't recommend it to anyone.

Comment: Sure! Let me rectify this.